# Error convert first character to upper case

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the first characters of all the span tags to upper case but i am getting an error: TypeError: a[0].toUpperCase is not a function.

```html
<div id="test">
  <h1>
    <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span>
   </h1>
</div>
```

```html
var x = document.getElementById("test");

function capital(a)
{
    return a[0].toUpperCase() + a.slice(1);
}
```

```html
var test=x.getElementsByTagName("span");
var b=capital(test)
console.log(b)
```

Comment: Try logging out the value of `a`. You will find it is not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName("span")` return a `HTMLCollection`. So if you want to use `toUpperCase()`, you need to loop through it and call `innerText`.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
console.log(x)

function capital(a){
    return a[0].toUpperCase() + a.slice(1);
}

for(el of x) {
  el.innerText = capital(el.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
        <h1>
          <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your were trying to convert element to uppercase, you need to get the text form the DOM then convert it. Using `innerHTML` or `textContent` to get text from the element will solve your problem.

**Here we go**

```js
let x = document.getElementById('test'); // your main element

let span = x.getElementsByTagName('SPAN'); // all span element within x

for( let char of span )
{
  // you should Add innerHTML in order to get the text
  console.log(char.innerHTML[0].toUpperCase() + '' + char.innerHTML.slice(1));

}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <h1>
    <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span>
   </h1>
</div>
```

Best practice to wrap the console each time when your write a single line code!

Cheer you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) css property:

```css
span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <h1>
    <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span>
   </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by applying `querySelecterAll` on the span tag and then convert the `textcontent` to the uppercase

```js
let myVal = document.querySelectorAll('span')
let arr=Object.values(myVal);
arr.map(m=>{
          let c=m.textContent;
          let text=c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +c .slice(1)
          m.textContent=text;
          }
         )
```

```html
<div id="test">
        <h1>
          <span>test1</span> <span>test2</span> <span>test3</span>
        </h1>
</div>
```